# Siphon water from washing machine into sink next to it

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a top-loading washing machine that has broke down and is full of water.  Instead of getting a bucket to manually collect the water, I was thinking I could use a tube to siphon the water out of it, but gravity could possibly get in the way.  I dont really want to leave the house to buy a pump, and I figured maybe I dont need one.

The sink height is the same as the top of the washing machine, the water will have to travel upwards about 1 foot then travel sideways about half a foot, then down into the neighboring sink.

Is this possible with just a tube? no pump?

Comment: I don't believe this is off topic - The context of the question indeed makes it look like an engineering question.   However, I'm not asking "how to get water out of the washing machine" - I'm asking if it is possible for water to go from the washing machine to the sink next to it using a siphon and not a pump.  The context is the story, much like a "word problem" in math.  Engineering aims to solve problems, and I'm not asking for someone to solve a problem for me, I'm asking if its possible for the water to move and the context helps frame the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A siphon from one open vessel (A) to another vessel (B) requires the water level in B to be lower than the water level in A.  As long as there is not a big air bubble in the siphon and the siphon is full of water, water will flow; but the flow rate will be approximately proportional to the difference in water height in the two vessels.

You might do better to siphon into a bucket on the floor, then dump the bucket into the sink.

Comment: Oh nice, I just remembered there is a drain on the floor nearby! Thanks!

Comment: this is more of an engineering comment: if there is a drain in the floor, just tip the washer over ;-).

Comment: @JEB I wouldn't want to tip the washer over, once it's tipping pretty far that's going to be awfully heavy and it will probably end up crashing to the ground.